# Binary invalid when execute Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Good Morning people. I am installing Postgres and when trying to create the database through the command line interface, postgres gives me the following message

```
invalid binary "c:/program files/postgresql/9.5/bin/createdb.exe "
```

he is not accepting any command. In print I gave the following command: createdb -E SQL_ASCII -T template0 "dbname" "dbusername"

I really do not know what else to do. because I already tested other versions of postgres 9.5 and the error remains. I'm trying Postgres 9.5 64 bit downloaded directly from the Postgres site

Comment: It seems there is an extra space at the end

Comment: its normal. I tested it on my machine

Comment: Are you sure it's normal? The space isnt supposed to be there I think. Check you config files for .exe and see if dirrection is with space.

Comment: I checked. Really written normal and .exe